# Join and multiple and conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony1, doctrine-1.2

I have users table

```
ID     NAME
1      John
2      Mike
3      Jack
```

and table with attributes and user IDs

```
USER   ATTRIBUTE
1      1
1      2
2      4
```

I need to select all users with attribute 1 AND 2 (so, in this example user #1 John). Attributes can be more than two.

I'v tried

```
SELECT * FROM user u LEFT JOIN attributes a ON u.id = a.user 
WHERE a.attribute = 1 AND a.attribute = 2
```

but of course it not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a combination of `IN()` and `GROUP BY ... HAVING` to achieve this. Also no need for a join if all you need is user ID's. So something like:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(attribute) AS attribute_count
FROM attributes
WHERE attribute IN(...) /* include your set of attributes here */
GROUP BY user
HAVING attribute_count = ? /* include number equal to number of attribute ID's in IN() above */
```

If you need user id's and names you can simply join this record set derived from the query above as a filter to the users table:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name
FROM user
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT user, COUNT(attribute) AS attribute_count
    FROM attributes
    WHERE attribute IN(...) /* include your set of attributes here */
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING attribute_count = ? /* include number equal to number of attribute ID's in IN() above */
  ) AS filter
  ON user.id = filter.user
```

Comment: It's big query and user table is the "core". What if I've already used `having` somewhere else? (to show users in X km from selected area)

Comment: @poh Actually as you typed your comment I was showing how to apply that filter to the main table via a join.

Answer (score 0):

having clause can be used with sum

```
SELECT u.id FROM user u 
INNER JOIN attributes a ON u.id = a.user 
group by u.id
having ( sum(case when attribute in (1,2) then 1 else 0 end) ) =2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all users for whom EXIST attribute 1 *and* 2. One way to solve this - as the name suggests - is the EXISTS clause:

```
select * 
from users u
where exists
(
  select *
  from user_attributes ua
  where ua.user = u.id
  and ua.attribute = 1
)
and exists
(
  select *
  from user_attributes ua
  where ua.user = u.id
  and ua.attribute = 2
);
```

Another way is this: Find all user ids that have both attributes, then select from users table.

```
select *
from users
where id in
(
  select user
  from user_attributes
  where attribute in (1,2)
  group by user
  having count(*) = 2 
);
```

In case there are duplicate entries in attributes, you would have to replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct attribute)`.

There are other ways to approach this. I think these two mentioned are rather straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a group by .... having

```
SELECT u.name
FROM
    users u
JOIN
    attributes a
    ON u.id = a.user
WHERE a.id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY u.name
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```